# php create_directory Permission denied: when attempting shell_exec script

Tags: php, apache, shell, ubuntu, permissions

When I try to `shell_exec('/home/user/scripts/./script')` I get the following error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::filesystem3::filesystem_error'
  what():  boost::filesystem::create_directory: Permission denied: "/.script"
Aborted (core dumped)
```

`shell_exec('whoami')` returns `www-data` on my web-facing php script.

The permissions to the directory and file are exactly the same:

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user123   group456     8246 Jun 25 06:10 script
drwxrwxr-x 7 user123   group456     4096 Jul 10 14:54 .
```

In fact I can `shell_exec('touch /home/user/scripts/test')` and it will create the file with no problem.

```
$ ls -l /home/user/scripts/test
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data          0 Jul 10 14:54 test123
```

This is how my groups are set up for each user:

```
$ groups user123
user123 : group456
$ groups www-data
www-data : group456
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: What happens if you run `/home/user/scripts/./script` from the command line?

Comment: It get the expected results. In fact, I've learned from this thread that I can also execute the command using `/home/user/scripts/script` and it works. It should be noted that the script I'm running is not a PHP script but a short C program, I am using PHP from a web-facing server on the same machine to call this script. I haven't had problems using PHP scripts to call this C script on the command line as root.

Comment: When you run it from php what is the exact error for `shell_exec('/home/user/scripts/script')` also `system('/home/user/scripts/script')`

Comment: The exact same error I pasted in the original post. If I take the same command in my `shell_exec` function and paste it on the command line I get the expected result.

Comment: I think your issue is your system is stopping apache from gaining root privileges. Do you have SELinux?

Comment: SELinux is installed (I think), I can find it using `locate` (`/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-40/scripts/selinux` and many other directories include files with the name `selinux`) but `which SELinux` returns nothing. This is an amazon ec2 install, by the way.

Comment: The C program looks like it's trying to create a directory.  Can you post the line from the C program where it attempts to do that?

Comment: Can you also add `/var/log/messages` to your question?

Comment: Actually the C program is the bitcoin daemon, I'm running some very simple RPC commands to get the network hashrate and connected node count (example: `/home/user/bitcoin/src/bitcoind getdifficulty` which is what `/home/user/script/script` in my original question refers to). Millions of people use the exact same source code, it can't have an error (bitcoin would be worthless if it were buggy!). I'm expecting the C program to return an integer and a float. @PoX there is no such file as `/var/log/messages` in my install, the error I'm getting is from `/var/log/apache/error.log`

Comment: ok so you are using ubuntu I should have guessed from www-data check `/var/log/syslog` for messages

Comment: Nothing in there besides the message every 30 min for my unrelated cron jobs. I also disabled SELinux and I'm still getting errors. I'm about to give up and just make a cron to store this info to the database every minute then read it using PHP... I really would like to be able to `shell_exec` executables from PHP but it doesn't seem like this is going to happen.

Comment: The problem was with the way the C program itself handles memory, not shell_exec, php or apache. 

Answer (score 1):

The script your running has a typo:  it's trying to make the folder `/.script` in the *root* folder instead of `./script` (relative path).

Comment: I don't understand, how is it a typo? I can run this exact page from command-line using `#!/usr/bin/php` and it works fine, I run most of my scripts by typing `./scriptname` in the command line, why does it fail on apache but not on command line?

Comment: The scripts error message said that it failed to create `/.script` which is a folder called `.script` located in the root folder `/`.  Either 1) the script you're trying to run from PHP has a typo, 2) you copy/pasted the error message wrong, or 3) boost is outputting incorrect error messages.
You can always try a `chdir('/home/user/scripts`)` before running the command to make sure it's using the correct PWD.

Comment: There are no typos, I have not copy/pasted anything wrong, and I tried your suggestion: `chdir` didn't work, I arrive at the same error as in my original post.

Comment: More specifically, with the following `chdir` command at the beginning of my php page:
`chdir('/home/user/scripts');`

I attempt these following commands:
`shell_exec('./script')` -- results in the error message in my OP...
`shell_exec('script')` -- results in a new error message... `sh: 1: script: not found`...
`shell_exec('sh script')` -- results in some weird `ELF: not found` and syntax error messages.

Comment: is this an executable or shell script you will get `ELF: not found` if you source an executable

Comment: @Joey - My main suggestion is to check the program you're running from PHP, the one located at `/home/user/scripts/script`.  That program is trying to make the directory `/.script` and failing (rightfully so).  I believe that to be in error as you more-than-likely meant to make the directory `script` in the current directory, not `.script` in the **root** directory.  If you actually are trying to make one in the root directory, please clarify that.  You'll need root directory permissions for that.

Comment: I don't want to create a directory, I want to run the script named `script` in the `/home/user/script` folder. Also, my `www-data` has directory permissions, as I've stated in my OP. I have tested `touch` and `mkdir` through `shell_exec` in the `/home/user/script/` directory, and both succeed without failure. I can't seem to execut this `script` program from `shell_exec` in my apache PHP configuration, for whatever reason.

Comment: @PoX `/home/user/scripts/script` is indeed an executable

Comment: @Joey - Fair enough.  The reason I'm focusing on the C program the shell kicks off is because the `boost::filesystem::create_directory` error message is from the C program, not PHP.  I would add `echo $PWD; whoami;` to the beginning of the shell script that runs the C program.  Run it from PHP and run it from the command line then post the output?

Comment: `shell_exec('pwd')` returns `/var/www` as expected, and `shell_exec('whoami')` returns `www-data`, I see what you're saying about the C program returning this error. I'm not really sure how that's possible, though, unless PHP is somehow passing arguments that I'm not seeing? For clarification, I'm not running a shell script, I am using this PHP page to execute the C program (I've been using PHP with CURL recently from the command line). I called my C program a "script" since it's small and doesn't do much, which was a mistake that caused a lot of confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to execute script at `/home/user/scripts/./script` then you should run as `shell_exec('sh /home/user/scripts/script')`

When you add `./` there on path its interpreted differently.

When you pass `./script` - You are referring to filename `script` in current directory.

Also you are actually getting error from your c program which tells us your system is stopping apache to gain root privileges. You can `audit2allow` to let apache gain needed privileges.

Comment: This is interesting, I didn't realize `sh` and `./` had different meanings. Could you possibly elaborate on the differences in these two commands, because AFAIK it's near impossible to search for a term like `./`.
Anyway, I'm still getting some errors: `ELF: not found` `Syntax error: "(" unexpected` `cannot create 0?A@` 
Using `shell_exec('sh /home/user/scripts/script')`

Comment: ./filename  means you refer to filename in current directory.

Comment: How is it possible that I can write a php script in `/home/user2/somedir/altscript.php` which contains the line `shell_exec('/home/user/scripts/./script')` and it works?

Comment: other user having same ini settings? if not that points to `safe_mode_exec_dir` setting being issue

Comment: safe mode is off, as far as I can tell -- `safe_mode = Off` from `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`

Comment: I think SELinux might be the culprit, how would I modify it so apache has rights to execute applications/executables?